# How create few folders in var/www on debian 9

Tags: debian

On debian 7 after instalation i could go to `/var/www/` and make some new folders like `/test1`  `/test2` etc and when i type my `IP/test1` i saw index of folder

on Debian 9 i see only `/var/www/html` and when i create `/var/www/test1` i have no access. How can i change this? i tried make vhost, a2ensite test1 and a2dissite default , restart apache2 etc and nothing.

I coudn't find anyu info from internet, or maybe i am looking tyoe wrong words.

Comment: sudo mkdir -p /var/www/<foldername>

Answer (score 1):

You need install apache or nginx for web service. 
Apache Installation for Debian 9 (if you not installed)

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install apache2
```

File Name `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
Correct your DocumentRoot directory here, default DocumentRoot is

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

if you want to make any folder on `/var/www/` directory then you need to change your DocumentRoot in apache settings. 
File Name `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
Make is

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

Hope it will help you!